# Regex extract last numbers from String

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings which are indexed and are dynamic.
For example:

```
name01,
name02,
name[n]
```

now I need to separate name from index.
I've come up with this regex which works OK to extract index.

```
([0-9]+(?!.*[0-9]))
```

But, there are some exceptions of these names. Some of them may have a number appended which is not the index.**(These strings are limited and I know them, meaning I can add them as "exceptions" in the regex)**

For example,

```
panLast4[01]
```

Here the last '4' is not part of the index, so I need to distinguish.
So I tried:

```
[^panLast4]([0-9]+(?!.*[0-9]))
```

Which works for `panLast4[123]` but not `panLast4[43]`

*Note: the "[" and "]" is for explanation purposes only, it's not present in the strings*

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are the indexes always going to start after the 0 ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis no, `panLast4[123]` and `panLast4[43]`.

Comment: 0 is for the first 10 numbers...

Comment: [Seems to work](http://regex101.com/r/rI4uA6)? Unless I'm missing the point, can you give expected sample input/output?

Comment: It does not work for panLast445 for example, the extracted index should be 45 not 445. That's why I tried `[^panLast4]([0-9]+(?!.*[0-9]))` which is close but still doesn't work for indices starting with 4.

Comment: The id comes within the brackets or you just wrote them for better understanding?

Comment: Yes for better understanding only

Comment: I think i'm not understanding, sometimes a number may come appended and sometimes not? How do you identify these cases? Does this appended number has more than one digit?

Comment: Sorry probably I didn't describe well. There is a number always, but for some strings, one number does not represent the index. For example panLast4 - 4 here is not part of the index but part of the name.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Nevertheless, my point is.. How do you know if the id of `name01` is `01` and not just `1` (because the `0` is appended)?

Comment: The strings which have a number appended to the name are limited and I know them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the split method with this pattern:

```
(?<!^panLast(?=4)|^nm(?=14)|^nm1(?=4))(?=[0-9]+$)
```

The idea is to find the position where there are digits until the end of the string `(?=[0-9]+$)`. But the match will succeed if the negative lookbehind allows it (to exclude particular names *(`panLast4` and `nm14` here)* that end with digits). When one of these particular names is found, the regex engine must go to the next position to obtain a match.

Example:

```
String s ="panLast412345";
String[] res = s.split("(?<!^panLast(?=4)|^nm(?=14)|^nm1(?=4))(?=[0-9]+$)", 2);
if ( res.length==2 ) {
    System.out.println("name: " + res[0]);
    System.out.println("ID: " + res[1]); 
}
```

An other method with `matches()` that simply uses a lazy quantifier as last alternative:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(panLast4|nm14|.*?)([0-9]+)");
String s = "panLast42356";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if ( m.matches() && m.group(1).length()>0 ) {
    System.out.println("name: "+ m.group(1));
    System.out.println("ID: "+ m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: This is splitting but not getting all digits of the index.
For example. `"panLast4455".split(regex) -> [panLast4] [4]`, but the index should be `[455]`

Comment: @isah: you need to use the limit parameter of the split method. I will post an example.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I don't quite understand your explanation but it's not your fault, I'm a bit regexophobic.

Comment: @isah: There is a more simple method, I will add it.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks

Comment: More zero-width poetry. :)